# Handling Events

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

#### Summary

I'm working on a game where there is multiple Events happening.
Events such as move, get hit, eat...etc.
The objective is to be able to execute a function whenever one of the events is present
There are three parts of an Event where a function can execute, OnStart/During/OnEnd.

**For example**, 
GetHit trigger X Function (Triggered by OnStart)
Eating will trigger Y Function every second (Triggered by During)
AfterUseSkill will trigger Z Function (Triggered by OnEnd)

**The problem is**, I only know how to trigger it the moment an Event executes such as OnEat, OnGetHit...etc by using methods such as delegates or the observer pattern. I'm unsure how to go about it when other phases such as WhileEating, WhileMoving is involved. Overall, I just need a solid way to identify what Event is running, which phase it is in (Start/During/End), I should then be able to use this information to determine which function to trigger. The only thing in my mind is having the Observer Pattern send out messages for each Phase, but I'm very hesitant to do so because I think it might be inefficient.

*Sorry if my structure is abit off, it is my first time question. Any kind of help, even if just a point to the right direction will be appreciated (Especially since I'm a newbie at Event Handling). Thank you!*

Comment: You may define some `bool IsEating` property and set it to `true` at the beggining of the handler and reset to `false` before exit from the handler.

Comment: Hey Oma. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Events in C# are fire-and-forget; there is no built-in way to maintain state. In your case, you might want to have something like `OnStartedEating()` and `OnFinishedEating()` in which you maintain the `IsEating` state. Then when `OnHit()` is triggered, you can check if `IsEating` is `true`, the in-game-object was hit while eating.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question! It is just very hard for me to grasp the concept without feeling like I'm hard-coding the thing. Do I just create those functions and variables for each action? When I'm casting skill, eating, moving, receiving/inflicting statuses/damage, it feels like there's so much and I fear that it is very hard to manage and control without a proper system.